# How to set property in jms selector in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jms, mule, activemq-classic, selector

I want get message in queue (in) and I want correlate messages. 
I must to put value from property in jms selector in Groovy but this not works.

The message is not picked up from the queue.

```
<script:transformer name="some">
            <script:script engine="groovy">
                <property key="id" value="123" />
                <script:text>
                    String url = "jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3Did";
                    return muleContext.client.request(url, 0);
                </script:text>
            </script:script>
        </script:transformer>
```

Some intresting is that works this:

```
jms://queue.in?selector=MULE_CORRELATION_ID%3Did
```

but I don't want above.

I want use another property name.

Not works this:

```
jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3Did
```

and this:

```
jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3D+id
```

and this:

```
jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3D+"id"
```

and this:

```
jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3Did
```

but works this (some interesting):

```
jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3D'123456'
```

but i don't want above.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Hurra! I did it :)

It works this:

```
jms://queue.in?selector=someId%3Did+'$id'
```